# How to checkout an older revision of an individual file?

Tags: cvs, vcs-checkout

I need to see what a file looks like then it was in revision X, but cvs checkout only accept a whole module as parameter, I don't want to check out the whole module in certain revision, because the whole project is rather big, how can I checkout individual files of a certain revision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a filename and a revision to checkout like this:

```
cvs co -r rev filename
```

For example:

```
cvs co -r 1.4.30.1 a/very/large/project/MyFile.h
```

Comment: OK, I need to provide absolute path beginning with module name